# how to perform a dynamic type test with an interface type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This is a SSCCE. The below code:

```
// @flow    
'use strict';

declare interface ICat {
    purr(): string;
}

class Animal {
    askToBeStrokedAsACat() {
        strokeAsACat(this); // Flow complains here
    }
}

function strokeAsACat(a: ICat) {
    a.purr();
}


class Cat extends Animal {
    purr() {
        return 'purr';
    }
}

const cat = new Cat();
cat.askToBeStrokedAsACat();
```

... results in [Flow](https://flowtype.org/) complaining at the function call of `strokeAsACat`.
The complaint is (edited for brevity):

```
property `purr` of ICat not found in class Animal
```

The complaint is reasonable and understood.

According to what is written on [dynamic type tests](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#_) I should be able to simply do the following:

```
class Animal {
    askToBeStrokedAsACat() {
        if (this instanceof ICat)
            strokeAsACat(this);
    }
}
```

... instead the above fails with:

```
ICat. type referenced from value position
```

Plus, since interfaces are transpiled away, `ICat` isn't available at runtime so the above fails when running with:

```
ReferenceError: ICat is not defined
```

As such, the only way to ascertain that the `this` handle at that point is an `ICat`-like object is to do the following:

```
class Animal {
    askToBeStrokedAsACat() {
        if (this instanceof Cat)
            strokeAsACat(this);
    }
}
```

... but this is [nominal, not structural typing](https://flowtype.org/docs/classes.html#_) and defeats the purpose of using the interface `ICat` as if I add a couple more `ICat-like` classes I would have to write my dynamic type test as:

```
(this instanceof Cat) || (this instanceof BobCat) || (this instanceof Lynx)
```

So my questions are:

1. is there a way to perform a structural dynamic type test for `interface` ?
2. is there some other way to effectively silence Flow's complaints for that particular line ?

My `Flow` version is:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0 | grep flow-bin
├── flow-bin@0.27.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to perform a structural dynamic type test for interface

No, it's impossible. You can test the object has a property and it's a function, but how would you know it's signature at runtime?

You should rarely need it, though. In your code, for example, you can just leave `askToBeStrokedAsACat` empty on `Animal` and override it in `Cat` subclass.

Comment: This is an SSCCE, so yes in this particular example you can put the `askToBeStrokedAsACat` in the `Cat` "subclass" as you say but in the real case (where this was reduced from) it was necessary for the code to remain in the base class. More importantly, I don't think your reasoning about "how would you know its signature at runtime" is correct. All Flow annotations are transpiled away at runtime but this doesn't stop Flow from making all kinds of useful type checks anyway.

Comment: Flow  analyses runtime constructs to prove that code is safe and would execute as expected. If there is no way to check something at runtime, there is no way for Flow to infer, that what you are doing is safe.